# Diode xstic in LTspice

Tags: diodes

I want to plot the forward diode I vs the V
But i'm getting the wrong result probably because the x axis is not the diode voltage.
How do I change this?
I put the clamp at point A
[image]

Comment: Why are you plotting with a log Y-axis?

Comment: I need that to extract values for some calculations

Comment: You can extract values from the linear axis, just as well. Datasheets do not show log axis in the I/V curves. What exactly are these calculations that force you to show a log axis which shows the exact same values compared to a linear axis?

Comment: The diode factor, n in I=I_s(exp (V/n*V_T)-1)

Comment: As I said, whether you have a log axis, or linear, the readings will be the same, and for your particular case you don't need a log axis to extract `n` -- simple mathematics will do, while also showing a familiar trace as seen in the datasheet with a linear axis.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pick the right net name when selecting the Quantity Plotted.
Therefore, you'd better label the net name first, because net names may change when you change your circuit. See example below where I named the net "ANODE".
(I used a different diode and lowered the resistor value in order to get a bigger range in diode drop.)

[image]

Comment: I'm quite a beginner in this, sorry. How did you make the quantity plotted to be V(ANODE)? I'm not able to change it on my side even after creating a label net

Comment: @Mana In the graph, right click on the horizontal axis, you'll see the popup screen "Horizontal Axis". Enter ```V(``` + the net name/label net (in my case: "ANODE") + ```)``` at Quantity Plotted.

Answer (score 0):

Where it says "quantity plotted" you need to change that by placing a net name (such as "Vx") on the diode's anode (A) and then selecting "Vx" as the quantity to be plotted.